# PL/SQL inherit rowtype

Tags: oracle, plsql

I know Oracle PL/SQL allows to create object sub type using the "under" keyword. But is it possible to create a subtype that inherit the RowType of a particular table?

For example, if there is a table named Customer and I want to create an object type that has all attributes in Customer table with extra fields.

I tried:

```
create or replace type t_sub_type as object under Customer%RowType (
  price NUMBER
);
```

Of course, the code fails to compile. So is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: No it's not possible. `customer%rowtype` is a record(`customer` is of record data type) not an object.

Comment: So is there any suggestion to create an object type with all attributes from a table and with some extra fields?

Comment: All attributes need to be specified explicitly.

Comment: Back In The Day (early-to-mid-90s) Kyle Brown of Knowledge Systems Corp. and Bruce Whitenack of Object People came up with a bunch of patterns for dealing with the issues raised by trying to store objects into a plain-jane relational database (i.e. one without built-in support for objects (e.g. Oracle's TYPEs) or inheritance (e.g. table inheritance in Postgresql). They called it Crossing Chasms, and it looks like the papers are [still available on the Knowledge Systems Corp website](http://www.ksc.com/articles/index.htm). You might want to give them a read-through. Share and enjoy.

Comment: The basic paper on Crossing Chasms was included in the book "Pattern Languages of Program Design 2", which is [available from Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Languages-Program-Design-v/dp/0201895277).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless `customer` happens to be an object table.  If `customer` is a regular old table, `customer%rowtype` is a record, not an object, so it cannot be inherited from.  If you created an object type `customer_typ` and created a table `customer` of  those object types, then you could create a subtype of `customer_typ`.  Something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create type customer_typ
  2    as object (
  3      name varchar2(100),
  4      address varchar2(1000),
  5      phone varchar2(30)
  6    )
  7*   not final
SQL> /

Type created.

SQL> create table customer_tbl of customer_typ;

Table created.

SQL> create type subcustomer_typ
  2    under customer_typ (
  3      newColumn number
  4    );
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> desc subcustomer_typ;
 subcustomer_typ extends SCOTT.CUSTOMER_TYP
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(100)
 ADDRESS                                            VARCHAR2(1000)
 PHONE                                              VARCHAR2(30)
 NEWCOLUMN                                          NUMBER
```

Of course, I'm hard pressed to imagine a case where this would make a great deal of sense.  But it is possible.  If you can describe why you want to inherit from a `%rowtype` record, we may be able to suggest some alternative approaches.